# Express fileupload mv() function override the existing image if the same name is given but retaining old dimensions

Tags: node.js, express

Express mv() method replaces the file but retains the old file's dimensions if two files with same name but different dimensions are uploaded. Please help to fix this issue.

For ex. If I move image-1 with name "pic1" having resolution 1200X1000 and then after some time I move image-2 with the same name "pic1" having different resolution 1800X1200. I could see the latest image being moved. But it still shows same old image's resolution. I use sharp js to get the resolution.

Code:

```
 let fileInfo = req.files.fileInfo; 

 fileInfo.mv(`/tmp/${fileInfo.name}`, function() {
    console.log("File is moved");
 });
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It's not clear.

Comment: Kindly review it now if it's clear. @LinDu

Comment: You need provide a minimal, reproducible code example